# How closely does "First Blood" portray the contemporary attitude towards war veterans?

Tags: realism, first-blood

How closely does the movie "First Blood" (1982) portray the contemporary ‍public attitude towards the returning Vietnam War veterans?

Does this trend still continue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's part of the reason why this movie was so popular, and in the directors commentary Sylvester Stallone credits anti-Vietnam attitudes for making the film a success.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Blood) has the film labelled as *"First Blood was a post-Vietnam War psychological thriller"*.

An interesting article on [American war films](http://www.historytoday.com/michael-paris/american-film-industry-vietnam) proposes the idea that First Blood represents American's lack of willingness to win the Vietnam war. Where the soldiers were capable both in skills and equipement, but altermately failed cause of a lack of support from the American public.

Rambo has flash backs to his imprisonment during the war as a POW, which are triggered by his false prosecution by the town Sheriff William Teasel. A town ironically called "Hope". The Sheriff is a representation of American anti-Vietnam attitudes.

The soldier without a war is a common theme in many reality and fantasy films. Where the soldier fails to reintegrate into a society that is responsible for his existence.

[Soldier (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120157/) is a perfect example.

[image]